# Direct Limit of Sheaves on a Noetherian Topological Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was working on Exercise 1.11, Chapter 2, Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*. The question is

Let $\left\{\mathscr{F}_i\right\}$ be a direct system of sheaves on a noetherian topological space $X$. In this case show that the presheaf $U \mapsto  \varinjlim \mathscr{F}_i(U)$ is a sheaf.

My problem is that I don't know how to use the Noetherian condition. I know that being Noetherian implies that each open set is quasi-compact and hence we only need to consider finite open covering when checking the sheaf axioms. But checking on finite covering is also difficult me. Besides, I don't think it is possible to do so, because the expression for direct limit involves quotients and it is hard to dertermine whether an element is zero (for example, when $\mathscr{F}_i$ are sheaves of groups, $\varinjlim \mathscr{F}_i(U) = \bigoplus \mathscr{F}_i(U)/S$, where $S$ is generated by $s_j-\varphi_{ij}(s_i)$, $\forall i\le j$).

Answer (score 2):

By the construction of the direct limit, any "eventual" equality happens at some finite stage - that is, if $\{F_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a directed system with maps $\varphi_{i,j}:F_i\to F_j$, and $f_\alpha\in F_\alpha$ and $f_\beta\in F_\beta$ are equal in $\varinjlim F_i$, there exists some $\gamma$ with $\gamma\geq\alpha$ and $\gamma\geq\beta$ such that $\varphi_{\alpha,\gamma}(f_\alpha)=\varphi_{\beta,\gamma}(f_\beta)$. Combining this with your observation that every subset of a noetherian topological space is quasi-compact, now you know that you only have finitely many pieces of data to keep track of, and this should let you solve the problem.

For instance, if you want to check the locality condition, suppose you have a section $s$ of the direct limit which is locally equal to zero on some open cover. By quasi-compactness, we may assume the cover is finite, say $\{U_\alpha\}_{1\leq\alpha\leq n}$; now for $s$ and each of $\varinjlim \mathcal{F}_i(U_\alpha)$ as $\alpha$ varies, we can find an $i$ and an $s_i$ and an $i_\alpha$ and an $s_{i_\alpha}$ with $s=\varphi(s_i)$ and $s|_{U_\alpha}=\varphi(s_{i_\alpha})=0$ where $\varphi:\mathcal{F}_i\to\varinjlim \mathcal{F}_i$ is the map to the limit.
Now apply the property of a directed system to find a common upper bound $j$ in $I$ of $i,i_1,\cdots,i_n$ so that $\varphi_{i,j}(s_i),\varphi_{i_{\alpha},j}(s_{i_\alpha})\in \mathcal{F}_j(U_\alpha)$ are sections of a common sheaf and all the $\varphi_{i_\alpha,j}(s_{i_\alpha})=0$. By locality for the sheaf $\mathcal{F}_j$, the section $\varphi_{i,j}(s_i)$ is the zero section, so $s=\varphi_i(s_i)=\varphi_j(\varphi_{i,j}(s_i))=0$ too. The gluing is similar, I'll leave that one for you.